# Deploying OVF with 3 VMDK's using JAVA VI telling me the storage is corrupt on VM startup

Tags: java, vmware

I have used the code from: http://www.doublecloud.org/2010/04/how-to-import-and-export-ovf-packages/
to deploy an OVF template with 2 VMDK's,

After deployment I received VM startup error telling me i need to unmount the storage and run xfs_repair.

The OVF is a CentOS operating system (VMDK1) other VMDK is the data - the problematic disk.
In other deploy tries it deploys the OVF with no errors on startup.
In case of a manual deploy there was no error (never encountered it before).
If i go to the vCenter and manually delete the 2'nd disk the startup is with no errors.
So it has something to do with the 2'nd VMDK.
I also have a .md file for the VMDKs and it is correct.

Any thoughts why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding sleep period between VMDK's upload